# Mysql union clause identify tables

Tags: mysql, select, union

I have a mysql table which holds lots of data across multiple tables. So to get it all out, I think the best bet is to use a UNION clause, however I also want to know which table the results come from as some have multiple values and some are null.

The following sql does not appear to work but I cant see whats wrong.

```
 (SELECT *, `2` AS 'cat' from `2` where `recid` = 'cneta0ld00ah')
  UNION
 (SELECT *, `3` AS 'cat' from `3` where `recid` = 'cneta0ld00ah')
  UNION
 (SELECT *, `4` AS 'cat' from `4` where `recid` = 'cneta0ld00ah')
  UNION
 (SELECT *, `5` AS 'cat' from `5` where `recid` = 'cneta0ld00ah')
```

All Tables look something like the following are are named, 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.

```
 recid         | item
 -------------------------
 cneta0ld00ah  |   1
 cneta0ld00ab  |   1
 cneta0ld00ad  |   3
```

I cant change the name of the tables as its an import from a very old database which we are trying to convert and extract data from.

If I run it without the 'table-name' AS 'cat', then it runs fine, as soon as I try to add in the table name it throws an error saying

```
Unknown column '2' in 'field list'
```

It seems to be thinking 2 is a column name?

Comment: Is there a reason why are you using `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Erm no, just thought UNION might be the way to go. Just noticed that UNION removes duplicate rows, its possible each table will return an item of 1, which im wondering if that will return just 1 row. ALL returns all rows? Any other reason to use ALL?

Comment: `UNION` takes additional time to remove duplicates. If you just need to combine data without duplicates, `UNION ALL` is much faster as it does not remove duplicates. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the backticks you have around the 'table-name' AS 'cat'. Backticks are for quoting table and column names, not strings. You should use single quotes instead:

```
 (SELECT *, '2' AS 'cat' from `2` where `recid` = 'cneta0ld00ah')
  UNION
 (SELECT *, '3' AS 'cat' from `3` where `recid` = 'cneta0ld00ah')
  UNION
 (SELECT *, '4' AS 'cat' from `4` where `recid` = 'cneta0ld00ah')
  UNION
 (SELECT *, '5' AS 'cat' from `5` where `recid` = 'cneta0ld00ah')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do all the tables have the same structure? In a `Union`, with `select *`, they need to.

If so, try removing the brackets

```
SELECT recid, item, `2` AS `cat` from `2` where `recid` = 'cneta0ld00ah'
UNION 
SELECT recid, item, `3` AS `cat` from `3` where `recid` = 'cneta0ld00ah'
```

Comment: Tables 2-5 definitely do, some of the later ones dont which I will have to work round at a later date, but those above do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

```
(SELECT *, `2` AS 'cat' from `2` where `recid` = 'cneta0ld00ah')
 UNION ALL
(SELECT *, `3` AS 'cat' from `3` where `recid` = 'cneta0ld00ah')
 UNION ALL
(SELECT *, `4` AS 'cat' from `4` where `recid` = 'cneta0ld00ah')
 UNION ALL
(SELECT *, `5` AS 'cat' from `5` where `recid` = 'cneta0ld00ah')
```

`UNION` should be used when you are selecting related information, similar to `JOIN`, since only distinct values will be selected. `UNION ALL` does not remove duplicates and therefore also decreases the time required to find distinct values.

You should also always specify a column list, and not `SELECT *`.

Comment: Thanks the UNION ALL will definitely help with some queries, but my particular prolem was solved by the backticks as pointed out by Ike.